# How to do vector Normalization on columns using python function

Tags: python, pandas

The below table having 1000 rows but here let's consider 3 rows:

| Date | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-24 | 100 | 1234 |
| 2021-02-01 | 200 | 6789 |
| 2020-04-30 | 300 | 4324 |

[image]

where `m` is the number of rows in the dataset and `n` is the number of columns. `i` varies along rows and `j` varies along the column.

For each row of Column `B` and `C`, the formula I tried applying is:

```
df['B'] = df1['B']  / np.sqrt((df['B'].pow(2)).sum())
df['C'] = df1['C']  / np.sqrt((df['C'].pow(2)).sum())
```

I want to write the same code using Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need processing mupliple columns by list use:

```
cols = ['B','C']
df1[cols] = df1[cols]  / np.sqrt((df1[cols].pow(2)).sum())
print (df1)
         Date         B         C
0  2022-07-24  0.267261  0.151539
1  2021-02-01  0.534522  0.833711
2  2020-04-30  0.801784  0.531001
```